# Http request failed: the timeout was reached in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App that calls different Azure Functions through generic webhook.

Till yesterday, the Logic App was working fine but today, I am noticing logic app is failing randomly. Some runs fails on function "A" and some runs fails on function "B". Error message of failure is same for every run. Following is the error message.

> **REASON**
>
> **Code**
>
> BadRequest
>
> **Message**
>
> Http request failed: the timeout was reached.

I have also tried by cloning the Logic App but error is still there.

Comment: Can you reach your Azure Function out of the Logic App context ? Did you configure CORS aspects on Azure Function ?

Comment: Yes, I can trigger the Azure function and it runs in few seconds successfully. No, I did not configure CORS aspects on any function.

Comment: Have a look to the CORS parameters of your azure function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue with a new deployment of Azure Functions that caused a small number of Logic App customers to run into timeouts. The build has been reverted, so you should no longer be seeing this issue.

Note that if your Function App is continually running (i.e. never idling), you may need to restart the Function App to mitigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Logic App requires that the CORS functionnality of the Azure Function to be configured.

You should check this link : [Azure Functions Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings).